# How to accept either remote or local version to resolve merge conflict in meld

Tags: git, version-control, meld

I am using meld version 3.18.0 for linux under the version control view to resolve merge conflicts.  This results in the familiar three panel view with the remote version on the left, the local version on the right, and the merged version in the middle.

Is there a way within this program to simply accept the remote or the local version (similar to git checkout --theirs my_file.txt)?

Also, there are times when for a particular line when the remote and local versions are different, and I would like to include both lines in the resolved version.  Is there a way to do this without selecting one and manually copying and pasting the second?

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the control key changes the →'s and ←'s to +'s and allows you to move the line without overwriting the corresponding line in the other file. You have the choice of moving the line above or below the existing line.